# How to transparent an item If user is behind it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an isometric game but I want to create transparency when the user goes behind the building or something else. How I can create that behaviour? Is the layers proper way to do that ?

Comment: You should give us some code so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

> Hey @Kingan, welcome to stack overflow.
> I achieved the same mechanic in my game you can also achieve this by following these steps :

> 1 _ first of all you need a shader to make gameObject invisible [Link to Shader](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cheapest-invisible-shader.148950/)

> 2 _ Draw a ray-cast from the center of the camera towards the player to detect objects between player and camera

```
// Some pseudo-code example

if(hitInfo.gameObject.tag != 'Player')
  // Get GameObject Material and make it invisible using shader
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
link to unity raycast docs